SPA + Storing JWT + REST API not accepting cookie auth
Everyone is talking about don't store jwt in localstorage for security purpose online.
But in actual fact, none of the project I work with using SPA + Rest API integration is implemented using the "Security Best Practice" in the event where the REST API don't support cookie based authentication.

Most Rest API (Internal + External) only authentication jwt using Bearer token, and not values from cookies.
Setting jwt as http only cookie in SPA essentially means that one cannot retrieve the jwt in cookie and passed it into bearer token via SPA.

There is 2 solution I see from here. Either the Rest API accepting cookie, or we have another backend proxy to SPA before passing to REST API.
Both of this require additional effort invested, especially when the REST API is not under your control, which most of the time end up is setting jwt in localstorage.
Is there any other approach ????? I would love to here if anyone of you actually following the security best practice of storing in cookies instead of local storage when using SPA + JWT with REST API.

A lot security best practices are trade-offs. Not following a practice (like not using HttpOnly cookies) doesn't necessarily mean there's a security hole, but it can mean that if you have a separate more real security problem, it will be easier for an attacker to take advantage.
Storing your tokens in LocalStorage is not the end of the world, but it's better to avoid it.
But if security is a priority for you, then there is a better solution. Don't directly talk from the browser to the third-party REST api but create an intermediate service on the same domain that makes the requests on your behalf and has its own session/cookie-based authentication system.
